# Qt "Does <filename> specify a file name or directory name on the target"

Tags: qt, qt-creator

we've been developing a Symbian application using Qt Creator under Ubuntu and everything worked fine. I just tried compiling under Windows and it seems that there is a problem locating a file I have defined in the .pro file

Here is the relevant section of this file:

> # Add more folders to ship with the application, here
>   folder_01.source = src/qml/MyGame
>   folder_01.target = qml
>   folder_02.source = assets
>   folder_02.target = .
>   file1.source = assets/Data.ini
>   DEPLOYMENTFOLDERS = folder_01 folder_02 file1

and here is what is printed in the compile output widget:

> Starting: "C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe"
>   Copying application data...
>   18 File(s) copied
>   102 File(s) copied
>   Does C:\Users\pek\Desktop\MyGame-build-desktop\Data.ini specify a
>   file name or directory name on the target 
>   (F = file, D = directory)?

If I comment out file1.source I don't get the error and the application runs fine, but then the file isn't copied at the destination. I also tried "assets\\Data.ini" and "assets\Data.ini" and "assets//Data.ini" with no success.

Notice that the folder "assets" isn't included in the message.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated (with votes! :P)

Answer (score 0):

This is a side effect of QT Creator using xcopy and probably the version of it you have installed in Windows. It doesn't know if 'Data.ini' is a file or a folder. There is no work-around I have found yet for getting past this besides editing qtquick2applicationviewer.pri or doing some kind of post-build copy of the file.

The lack of 'assets' in your error message is because it is displaying the target location. If you specify the target location as 'assets', it will appear:

```
file1.target = assets
```

The target location is calculated as `<output_directory>/<file1.target>/<last(split(file1.source, \\))>`